# greedy multiple knapsack (minimize/reduce number of bins)

Tags: python, greedy, knapsack-problem

actually, I already have a partial answer for this question, but I'm wondering if this small piece of greedy code can be generalized to something closer to the optimal solution.

> how I met this problem (not relevant for problem itself, but maybe interesting):
>
> I receive a large collection of objects (it's a set of profiles of dykes, and each dyke keeps more or less the same shape along its length), I can group them according to a property (the name of the dyke).  the output of my program goes to an external program that we have to invoke by hand (don't ask me why) and which can't recover from failures (one mistake stops the whole batch).
>
> in the application where I'm using this, there's no hard requirement on the amount of bins nor to the maximum size of the bins, what I try to do is to
>
> - keep the amount of groups low (invoke the program few times.)
> - keep the sets small (reduce the damage if a batch fails)
> - keep similar things together (a failure in a group is probably a failure in the whole group).

I did not have much time, so I wrote a small greedy function that groups sets together.

a colleague suggested I could add some noise to the data to explore the neighbourhood of the approximate solution I find, and we were wondering how far from optimal are the solutions found.

not that it is relevant to the original task, which doesn't need a true optimal solution, but I thought I would share the question with the community and see what comments come out of it.

```
def group_to_similar_sizes(orig, max_size=None, max_factor=None):
    """group orig list in sections that to not overflow max(orig) (or given max_size).

    return list of grouped indices, plus max effective length.

    >>> group_to_similar_sizes([1, 3, 7, 13])
    ([[2, 1, 0], [3]], 13)
    >>> group_to_similar_sizes([2, 9, 9, 11, 12, 19, 19, 22, 22, ])
    ([[3, 1], [4, 2], [5], [6, 0], [7], [8]], 22)

    result is independent of original ordering
    >>> group_to_similar_sizes([9, 19, 22, 12, 19, 9, 2, 22, 11, ])
    ([[3, 1], [4, 2], [5], [6, 0], [7], [8]], 22)

    you can specify a desired max size
    >>> group_to_similar_sizes([2, 9, 9, 11, 12, 19, 19, 22, 22, ], 50)
    ([[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4], [8, 7, 0]], 50)

    if the desired max size is too small, it still influences the way we make groups.
    >>> group_to_similar_sizes([1, 3, 7, 13], 8)
    ([[1], [2, 0], [3]], 13)
    >>> group_to_similar_sizes([2, 9, 9, 11, 12, 19, 19, 22, 22, ], 20)
    ([[1], [3, 2], [4, 0], [5], [6], [7], [8]], 22)

    max size can be adjusted by a multiplication factor
    >>> group_to_similar_sizes([9, 19, 22, 12, 5, 9, 2, 22, 11, ], max_factor=0.75)
    ([[2], [3], [4, 1], [5, 0], [6], [7], [8]], 22)
    >>> group_to_similar_sizes([9, 19, 22, 12, 5, 9, 2, 22, 11, ], max_factor=1.5)
    ([[2, 1], [6, 5], [7, 3, 0], [8, 4]], 33)
    """

    ordered = sorted(orig)
    max_size = max_size or ordered[-1]
    if max_factor is not None:
        max_size = int(max_size * max_factor)

    orig_ordered = list(ordered)
    todo = set(range(len(orig)))
    effective_max = 0

    result = []
    ## while we still have unassigned items
    while ordered:
        ## choose the largest item
        ## make it member of a group
        ## check which we can still put in its bin

        candidate_i = len(ordered) - 1
        candidate = ordered.pop()
        if candidate_i not in todo:
            continue
        todo.remove(candidate_i)

        group = [candidate_i]
        group_size = candidate

        for j in sorted(todo, reverse=True):
            if orig_ordered[j] + group_size <= max_size:
                group.append(j)
                group_size += orig_ordered[j]
                todo.remove(j)

        result.insert(0, group)
        effective_max = max(group_size, effective_max)

    return result, effective_max
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of your colleague to add some noise data, But may be it's better to make a few swaps in `ordered` after  you call `ordered = sorted(orig)`?

Comment: ah, yes, that was also my interpretation to "adding noise to the data".

Comment: @mariotomo Ok, I did not catch that. And just another thought in the same direction: what about defining min number of bins to a small number (2,3,4...)? I think it is some kind of a noise too...(?)